# Get road segment latitude, longitude around 100 km from a driver's journey path and snap off the road points to road segment

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2016 database (migrated from sqlserver 2005) with a table that includes, among other columns, Latitude and Longitude (like 36.13373, -79.96276; 36.13386, -79.96288) that describes road segments only. I have another table describing the user's driving data. Logically the Lat, long from the driving data should correspond to the road segment table. But due to GPS positioning error sometimes the driving data shows off the road paths.

1. I want to create a smaller reference table by selecting all the records from the Road segment table falling within 100 miles/Kms from the user's journey path.
2. I want to snap the driving path to the closest/logically correct road segment using the smaller table at records where they fall off the road due to data error.

Does anyone have any experience with handling similar kind of problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do my living with that. But why you want 100km? the gps error isnt that big. And are you  familiar with [Sql Spatial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ?

Comment: I have not actually figured out how much deviation is normally expected. 100 Km is just an arbitrary value. It can be 20. I am not familiar with sql spatial. Thanks.